# Converse statement

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logic

Let $g$ and $l$ be given positive integers. Prove that integers $x$ and $y$ exist satisfying $(x,y)=g$ and $[x,y]=l$ if and only if $g|l$.

I am facing problem in proving the converse statement.

The converse statement is not clear to me. Are we supposed to prove the existence (The existence of $x$ and $y$ having the property $(x,y)=g$ and $[x,y]=l$) OR property (the existence of $x$ and $y$ is known and now need to prove that they satisfy the property $(x,y)=g $ and $[x,y]=l $ )

Comment: You have to prove the existence of such $x$ and $y$, that is your first idea

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "converse". Given an implication $P \to Q$, its converse is $Q \to P$. But the statement that you have to prove is of the form $P \leftrightarrow Q$, so it is not clear which direction the converse refers to.